# How to split a DataSetIterator into testing and training iterator?

Tags: java, deep-learning, training-data, deeplearning4j

I am using Deeplearning4j and datavec, and I have a DataSetIterator object that represents all of my data, which is a time series. How can I split this into training and testing iterators? I check and the DataSetIterator Class's methods are deprecated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through your `DataSetIterator` and for each `DataSet` entry, create two new `DataSets`, each for train and test.

The key is to use the [splitTestAndTrain](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/nd4j/linalg/dataset/DataSet.html#splitTestAndTrain-double-) method, which accepts a `double fractionTrain` that will specify the amount of data to be trained (the rest to be tested). There are different overloads of the method, so you can choose the one that fits your needs best. If you wish to add all train and test datasets to a common iterator, you could store them in two different Lists, and get their corresponding iterator later. Something like:

```
List<DataSet> trainList = new ArrayList<>();
List<DataSet> testList= new ArrayList<>();

while (yourDataSetIterator.hasNext())
{
    DataSet ds = yourDataSetIterator.next();
    SplitTestAndTrain splData = ds.splitTestAndTrain(0.5); //half for each         
    DataSet trainDs = splData.getTrain();
    trainList.add(trainDs);
    DataSet testDs  = splData.getTest();
    testList.add(testDs);
    (...)
}

Iterator<DataSet> trainIterator = trainList.iterator(); 
Iterator<DataSet> testIterator  = testList.iterator();
```

As I don't really know the specific details of this library, the example just creates "basic" `iterators`. This may be customized so you create `DataSetIterators` instead.

Note that you may also need to shuffle the DataSet before splitting it (`ds.shuffle()`). You could find some examples [here](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/tree/aeb002d151ffcf785a46aba45a722d189de2e0df/datavec-examples/src/main/java/org/datavec/inputsplit)

---

If you wish to split it in an specific way, you could label the different entries and find the max index of the test dataset; Then, call [`splitTestAndTrain(int max)`](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/nd4j/linalg/dataset/DataSet.html#splitTestAndTrain-int-) method, which specifically splits the dataset regarding the max parameter. The [`sortByLabel`](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/nd4j/linalg/dataset/DataSet.html#sortByLabel--) method could also be helpful here.

---

[**`Adam Gibson`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5131255/adam-gibson) gave a great suggestion on the comments regarding other mechanism in order to split the `DataSetIterator`, which also seem to be a "more natural" way to do it, the [`DataSetIteratorSplitter`](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-data/deeplearning4j-utility-iterators/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/datasets/iterator/DataSetIteratorSplitter.java).

It offers the `getTrainIterator()` and `getTestIterator()` methods, which return the library's specific iterator, `DataSetIterator`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that almost solves my problem. However, my data is time series. so wouldn't my training data be the first part of the set and the test data would be the second part, split cleanly? In your code, for each batch, you split half into training and half into test, which would mess up the time series order I believe. How would you adjust it for a time series data set? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you know which is the end of the first part, you could call https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/nd4j/linalg/dataset/DataSet.html#splitTestAndTrain-int- this, so it gets just the number of tests

Comment: added an update, hope it helps somehow...i believe the key is to label every dataset in order to know where each one ends, so you can call splitTestAndTrain with an specific range

Comment: Just note you can also use the splitter: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-data/deeplearning4j-utility-iterators/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/datasets/iterator/DataSetIteratorSplitter.java

Comment: That's a really good tip, including it in the answer